# Python read last 10 emails from Outlook

Tags: python, email, csv, outlook

I can read my last email from my Outlook and send all the results according to each line's content.

However, I am unable to find the way to read my last 10 emails to be added to the fileCollect.txt file.

Any ideas how I could do this?  Here is my current code:

```
import win32com.client
import csv

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder


messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()



fileCollect = open("fileCollect.txt",'a')
delimiter = "¿"
fileCollect.write( str(message.Sender) + delimiter + str(message.Subject)+ delimiter + str(message.Body) )
fileCollect.close()


csvfile = open("csvfile.csv",'a')

with open("fileCollect.txt","r") as outfile:
    for line in outfile:
        if line.find("test") != -1:
            csvfile.write(line)

csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

The Items collection will not be sorted in any particular order until you actually sort it by calling Items.Sort. The VB script below sorts the collection by ReceivedTime in the descending order:

```
set messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("ReceivedTime", True)
set message = messages.GetFirst()
while not (message Is Nothing)
  MsgBox message.Subject
  set message = messages.GetNext()
wend
```

Comment: so for python, the key line is the messages.Sort("ReceivedTime", True)     ... obviously make the T in True uppercase.  note that Sort returns None so rather than messages = messages.Sort("ReceivedTime", True) just call it in place as shown in the example.

Comment: The sample above is VBA, not Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last 10 messages by specifying a negative index:

```
last_10_messages = messages[-10:]
```

This will return an array from messages[-10], which is the 10th to the last message, to the last message in the messages array.

Comment: win32com doesn't allow slicing. Instead you'll have to do something along the lines of for i in range(-1,-11,-1): message_list.append(messages[i]).

Comment: Thank you for your answers but where should I actually put the for loop? Sorry i'm actually new to python

Comment: You will want to replace the line "message = messages.GetLast()" with the for loop. Then make another for loop to iterate through and write the 10 messages to fileCollect.txt, so something like "for message in message_list:" after the "fileCollect = open..." line will work. See here for an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. use len(inbox.Items) to get the length of the inbox.
2. use inbox.Items.Item(i) to get i-th email in the inbox.

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.item